# First TableView section title doesn't scroll Swift 4

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm building the `SalesViewController`for my app and it consists of a `TableView` showing all items found in a date range. 
`Item`is child of `Order` and it has `category`, `date`, `itemId`, `itemName`, `price`attributes all `String`.
I finally succeed in displaying the result of `itemFetchResultController` properly divided in sections as I had wrong `sortDescriptor`. In configuring `itemFetchResultController` I want use `category` property from fetched `Item` entities to be the section displayed title in populated `TableView`. My goal is, dough I'm not sure it would be possible or how to achieve it, to only have 1 row per `itemName` in  its section but know ho many of it have been found in fetch and use it to display sold value. It's the first time I use `sections` and it's all a bit confusing to me. I'm trying to follow Apple documentation sample code gives me a couple of errors in tableView's data source methods as you can see by commented out code. All other posts I found here on stack overflow are very old and in objective c so I don't find answers to my doubts. 
So far `TableView`gets populated correctly , but first section title doesn't move when scrolling.

Any Idea of what's causing this ?
As always many thanks.

Here is the code I'm using for `itemFetchResultController` :

```
lazy var itemFetchedResultController: NSFetchedResultsController<Item> =  {

        // first sortDescriptor filters the date range:  possibly change date from String to dates in both function and  CoreData and use "(date >= %@) AND (date <= %@)" instead of "BEGINSWITH" in predicate
        let itemFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Item>(entityName: "Item")
        itemFetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "category", ascending: true)]
        itemFetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "order.user.name == %@", UserDetails.fullName!)
        itemFetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "date BEGINSWITH %@", dateToFetch)
        let itemFetchedResultController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: itemFetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: "category", cacheName: nil)
        return itemFetchedResultController
    }()
```

`TableView` data source:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        // apple doc : trhrows an error : Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'NSFetchedResultsController<Item>'
//        if let frc = itemFetchedResultController {
//            return frc.sections!.count
//        }
//        return 0

            return itemFetchedResultController.sections!.count

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        guard let sections = self.itemFetchedResultController.sections else {
            print(" Error :no sections in fetchedResultController" )
            return 0
        }
        let sectionInfo = sections[section]
        return  sectionInfo.numberOfObjects

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "statisticsCell", for: indexPath) as! StatisticsTableViewCell
            cell.idInfoLabel.text = itemFetchedResultController.object(at: indexPath).itemId!
            cell.nameInfoLabel.text = itemFetchedResultController.object(at: indexPath).itemName!

    let item = itemFetchedResultController.object(at: indexPath).itemName!

    let productRequest: NSFetchRequest<Product> = Product.fetchRequest()
    productRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)]
    productRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", item)
    productRequest.fetchLimit = 1
    do {
        let fetch = try context.fetch(productRequest)
        cell.productImageView.image = UIImage(data: (fetch[0].productImage! as Data))
        cell.minimumStockInfoLabel.text = fetch[0].minimumStock
        cell.soldQuantityInfoLabel.text = fetch[0].soldQuantity

    } catch  {
        print("Error in fetching product for cell: \(error)")
    }

    return cell
}

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

//        guard let sections = self.itemFetchedResultController.sections else {
//            print(" Error : no sections in itemsFetchedResultController " )
//            return "empty"
//        }
//        let sectionInfo = sections[section]
//        return sectionInfo.name

        guard let sectionInfo = itemFetchedResultController.sections?[section] else {
            return nil
        }
        return sectionInfo.name

    }

        func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
//            if let sectionIndexTitles: FetchedResultController.sectionIndexTitles = self.itemFetchedResultController.sectionIndexTitles {
//                print(" Error : no sections in itemsFetchedResultController " )
//                return [""]
//            }
            return itemFetchedResultController.sectionIndexTitles
        }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String, at index: Int) -> Int {
        // apple doc : trhrows an error : Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Int'
//        guard let result = itemFetchedResultController.section(forSectionIndexTitle: title, at: index) else {
//            fatalError("Unable to locate section for \(title) at index: \(index)")
//        }
//        return result
       let result = itemFetchedResultController.section(forSectionIndexTitle: title, at: index)
        return result

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your `UITableView` style to grouped and your all section will scroll along with cells

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, that was it. I Was going mad looking for it.